# How do I copy a link in Lynx?

Tags: linux, lynx, linux-terminal

I'd like to copy the current link to the system's clipboard or write it to a file.

If it isn't possible, I guess I'd have to settle with opening it in an external browser (which I was avoiding in the first place, thus using Lynx), and then copying the opened URL. :-/

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Press <kbd>Shift+g</kbd> to show the address of the current document, <kbd>Shift+e</kbd> to show the address of the selected link. You can copy the text with your mouse (or the keyboard, if your terminal supports that).

Press <kbd>a</kbd> to save the address of a document or link to a (Netscape-alike) bookmark file, by default `~/lynx_bookmarks.html`. You can open this in a different browser, it's just HTML.

Comment: This works like a charm - thanks! I was wondering, though, what about links that are too long to fit in the status bar? How do I select/copy those (without having to save it to the bookmarks file and copy it from there)?

Comment: ① Scroll with the arrow keys left and right and copy the URL in pieces. Needs assembly in a text editor or similar.
② Resize the terminal emulator window and reduce the font size to minimum. Can fit about 350 characters for the displayed URL with my setup. Assign some keyboard shortcuts if you need to do this often.

Comment: I know this is old, but you can press L to show a list of all of the links on a page untruncated, and use the previously mentioned methods to copy it. Although, when you copy it there will be newline and padding characters if the link spans more than one line.

Comment: [`tmux` can be used for copying text on Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/58765/172800) (on Wayland copy to the system clipboard with e.g. [wl-clipboard](https://github.com/bugaevc/wl-clipboard).

Comment: Same works in `elinks`, just the bookmarks file is located in`~/.elinks/bookmarks`

Answer (score 2):

Sorry I am a bit late to this post, but I just saw this question. You can use the `EXTERN_PAGE` (default: ,) or `EXTERN_LINK` (default: .) keys to do what you want with the page url or selected url respectively. In the config you will also have to include something like `EXTERNAL:http:echo %s | xclip -selection clip-board:TRUE` into your config if using xorg to define a copy command. Of course, you can also use this for other commands like `EXTERNAL:http:mpv %s:TRUE` if you want to watch something directly.

I hope this helps anyone searching this thread.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, you can also use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> to save the URL of the current page or the current link (at least on my version 2.8.8).

(Unfortunately, I'm currently getting an error "Copy to clipboard failed", but maybe someone else is more lucky.)

Comment: I've also posted this answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6864548/how-can-i-copy-a-link-url-in-either-lynx-or-links-to-copy-to-vim/.

Comment: This doesn't work for me because control-S is the terminal emulator's flow control character, which freezes lynx.

Answer (score 0):

A simpler one-key solution is `=` which displays Document Info and where you may also right-click to copy link.